# Silicon Nano materials

Tags: semiconductor-physics, nanoscience

Bulk Si has indirect bandgap structure. But when we make Si into nano particles it behaves like a direct bandgap. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the main reason is a change in dimension(from classical to quantum) and size effects(structural changes, crystal symmetry changes). You can look at allotropes of carbon (fullerene, graphene, nanotubes, etc.) which have very different physical features between them and even between bulk. More details can be found in following article [1](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jpcc.8b02239).